# Image trace tool in Adobe Illustrator is not working as it is intended to

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I apply the image trace tool on the image it becomes complete white instead of becoming vector. Below are the before and after image result.

**Before:**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the image has not enough contrast. You should open it in an image editing program like Photoshop and make the grey lines darker or black.

Comment: Thanks for responding making the lines darker in Adobe Photoshop does a trick 

Comment: Can one not just adjust threshold?